# Is LiveData observer needed in Kotlin and SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, kotlin, android-livedata, observers

I came across such a code and have a question regarding it.
In the *ViewModel*, the variable *nights* is declared and formatted as follows:

```
 private val nights = database.getAllNights()

val nightsString = Transformations.map(nights) { nights ->
    formatNights(nights, application.resources)
}
```

*getAllNights ()* is a function in Dao that looks like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM daily_sleep_quality_table ORDER BY nightId DESC")
fun getAllNights(): LiveData<List<SleepNight>>
```

*getAllNights ()* is not called anywhere else in the code, but what surprises me the **LiveData observer** is nowhere else, despite this the displayed text is automatically updated on the screen every time I add something to database with the button:

```
  android:text="@{sleepTrackerViewModel.nightsString}" />
```

Is it only enough in Kotlin and SQLite to return Live Data in Dao and you do not need an observer? And if you need it when?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably they are using [Databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) that's why you can't see the observer no where.

You should have something like this on your layout file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.myapp.data.ViewModel" />
    </data>
</layout>
```

And in your build.gradle something like this:

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```